# I/O redirection in ssh command

Tags: bash, ssh, io-redirection

I wrote a bash script `rm_remote_file.sh` that ssh to a set of remote machines and delete a file. I used `&` at the end of each function call to run these command in parallel, the script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm_remote_file() {
    echo "Removing file on node $1:"
    ssh $1 'rm ~/test_file'
}

for node in node1.com node2.com node3.com; do
    rm_remote_file $node &
done
```

When test_file exists on each node - the `rm` command succeeds - the output of this script is:

```
Removing file on node node1.com:
Removing file on node node2.com:
Removing file on node node3.com:
```

I prefer having each hostname printed out. However, if the test_file does not exist on each node - the `rm` command fails - the output of this script is:

```
rm: cannot remove ‘~/test_file’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘~/test_file’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘~/test_file’: No such file or directory
```

So the printing of the nodes' host names are suppressed by this error message. I think this behavior has something to do with the I/O redirection and using things such as `2>&1` can solve the issue. But I would like to know why ssh command error message would suppress the echo command.

Note that this only happens with ssh command, the following script, which just removes some local files, would outputs both "Removing file" and the "No such file or directory".

```
#!/bin/bash

rm_file() {
    echo "Removing file..."
    rm ./$1
}

for file in test1 test2 test3 test4 test5; do
    rm_file $file &
done
```

Comment: It's not *guaranteed* only to happen with ssh, there's just more latency during the setup there so it's more likely.  With the local version, the `rm_file` functions are still being forked off and run in the background, but the `echo` happens very close to when the `rm` does. With the remote version, there's a big delay between the `echo` and the `rm` while the `ssh` transport is negotiated.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Why would the big delay between `echo` and `ssh` block the `echo` message? I tried to add a `sleep 5` in between `echo` and `rm ./$1` in the remove-local-files script, and I am still able to see both the `echo` messages and the `rm` error messages.

Comment: It *doesn't* block the message, but it means you've got a greater chance for ordering to be broken, so you get all three `Removing file on node $i` messages printed before *any* `rm` errors. Keep in mind also that in the `ssh` case, the exact amount of delay will vary a bit, so the order of the `echo`s and the order of the `rm` errors are particularly likely to be decoupled.

Comment: (To be very clear, I don't believe the claim in the question that the messages *ever were* blocked, and won't believe it until I see a [mcve]; more likely they're just happening elsewhere in your log, at a place you aren't looking, since the failure messages below them pushed them off the screen).

Comment: When we do not use `2>&1` at all, we do not see `echo` message when running remove-remote-files script, but we do see `echo` message when running remove-local-files script.

Comment: *nod* -- the `echo` is written to stdout since you aren't redirecting it, and the `rm` message is written to stderr, so without `2>&1` unifying everything on stdout they're going to potentially-different places. Since the code necessary to reproduce isn't given in the question, we can't say what/where those places are.

Comment: When we run `remove-local-files.sh`, even without 2>&1, the stderr and stdout somehow both show up in the terminal. I also confirmed that `echo` indeed prints to stdout and failed `rm` prints to stderr by running `./remove-local-files.sh > out 2>error`, and checked both `out` and `error`.

Comment: Yes, by default, in a terminal session, stderr and stdout are both directed to the TTY.

Comment: BTW, one thing you might consider is redirecting everything to a file and inspecting the file with tools that are aware of hidden characters. `rm_remote_file >log 2>&1` and then running, say, `cat -A log | less` may be informative; that way, any strings that might be interpreted by your terminal to overwrite previously-written content will be displayed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187758/discussion-between-xiangyu-and-charles-duffy).

Answer (score 0):

Add 2>&1 to ssh command, to that message and error stay in order:

```
ssh $1 'rm ~/test_file' 2>&1
```

Solution after discussion:

```
rm_remote_file() {
    echo "Removing file on node $1: $( ssh $1 'rm ~/test_file' 2>&1 )"
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's guaranteed. There are still two separate commands inside `rm_remote_file` that write to its inherited standard output, and it's still possible for all three `echo` commands to run before any one `ssh` writes its output.

Comment: I see three messages and then three errors being printed out, and there is no way to find out which message corresponds to which error. Most importantly, my question is more about why errors from ssh command would block echo message, but errors from local rm command would not.

Comment: @chepner Yes, you're  right: Other solution: `echo "Removing file on node $1: $( ssh $1 'rm ~/test_file' 2>&1 )"`

Comment: @Wiimm This solves the ordering issue and it gets the job done. However, I just want to understand why the following is happening: when we use the old script and do not use `2>&1` anywhere in the script or following `./remove-remote-files.sh`, the stdout would be blocked by the `rm` stderr. But when this runs locally, we can see both stdout and stderr.

Comment: Without `2&>1` there are to output queues: stderr and stdout. Both are managed by their own, even at script end. So message of one queue can pass the other one. Reasons may be buffering and processing by different processes. The early `2&>1` redirects stderr to stdout. And in the last variant, stderr is integrated into stdout.

Comment: @Wiimm Could you elaborate a bit on "So message of one queue can pass the other one"? What is the queue in this context? And by "pass", do you mean shading/blocking/suppressing?

Comment: stdout is usually buffered by several tools, and stderr not (or smaller buffer). So messages of stderr can be printed at console earlier than stdout, even if a stdout message was crated before.

Comment: @Wiimm, the distinction made re: default libc buffering behaviors is true, but not relevant here: Each instance of `echo` flushes its output before exiting, no matter what the FD is directed to; and likewise, each instance of `rm` flushes its stderr.